# How to create a pandas dataframe where the datatype of a column will be a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to create a pandas dataframe consisting of two columns. The first columns will of datatype int and the second one will be of dictionary type. Then insert data into the dataframe iteratively.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by inserting data iteratively? Do you have the data already? Why not initiate it together?

Comment: You *can* have a data frame with one column filled with `int`s and one column filled with `dicts`. But you won't get any benefit from `pandas` framework with this `dict` column, as jpp highlighted below

Comment: Agree with @RafaelC. Sounds like you just want a list of tuples whose first element is your int and the second is the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.

Pandas **dtypes**(*) are closely related to NumPy dtypes. There are some differences and additions, e.g. for `datetime` and `category`, but in the general the rule holds. Often these additional dtypes are wrappers around NumPy dtypes. The key here is series with these specifically defined dtypes are held in **contiguous memory blocks**. They can manipulated with vectorised computations.

A series which cannot be held in the fashion described above gets labelled with dtype `object`. This is nothing more than a **sequence of pointers** to arbitrary Python types. You should not consider this as an "array of dictionaries" in any vectorised sense. You can compare such a series to a list. You would never say that a list has "dtype `dict`" just because it contains dictionaries. Similarly, the fact that an `object` series only contains dictionaries doesn't make it a series of dtype `dict`.

(*) Notice I use "dtype" instead of "type". This is intentional. "dtype" has a specific and important meaning in relation to Pandas / NumPy, as the rest of my answer should demonstrate.

Comment: OP mentions nothing about effectiveness. You can insert elements of type int and dict would be of type object as you describe. I don't see the problem here?

Comment: Type has a very specific meaning with Pandas and NumPy. Throughout my answer I use `dtype`. It's crucial to understand the nuance. There's a "problem" with understanding, and that's the problem I'm trying to resolve with my explanation.

Comment: Ok fair, but it seems we quickly rush to answer questions with assumptions that simply can't be made by reading 2 rows of text.

Answer (score 0):

I might be totally wrong here (in the sense: **understanding what you really want**) but to create such a dataframe you could could pass empty pandas series specifying the dtypes you want to add, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':pd.Series([], dtype=np.int64),
    'B':pd.Series([], dtype='object')
})
```

And then, let us assume you have some data you want to add:

```
datatoinsert = [0, {'key':'value'}]
```

Then you can go ahead and use this formula:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = datatoinsert
```

---

`print(df)` and you have:

```
   A                 B
0  0  {'key': 'value'}
```

I do however agree with JPP that the dict column (which is of numpy dtype object won't give you any benefits, but the int one does and you might be interested in creating effectiveness around that)